# XpsDocumentWriter throwing error "Compressed part has inconsistent data length" on Write()

Tags: c#, .net, xps

I'm trying to write a XPS document. Currently "doc" is a FixedDocument with one PageContent object with a Child of type FixedPage with 7 UIElements as it's "Children". It's throwing an

`error      Message "Compressed part has inconsistent data length."`

Here's a sample

```
    private FixedDocument Document;
    private DocumentViewer Viewer;
    private FixedPage Page;
    private PageContent Content;
```

First, I'm successfully resetting the document and viewer:

```
    private void ResetDocument()
    {
        Viewer = new DocumentViewer();
        Document = new FixedDocument();
    }
```

I'm creating a Single New Page (I'm getting the same error for multiple pages)

```
    public void NewPage()
    {
        Page = new FixedPage();
        Content = new PageContent();
        ((IAddChild)Content).AddChild(Page);
        Document.Pages.Add(Content);
    }
```

I'm successfully adding UIElements to the Page

```
    public void AddVisualToPage(UIElement element)
    {
        Page.Children.Add(element);
    }
```

Then I'm getting the error in this part.

```
    public void SaveCurrentDocument(string name)
    {
        Viewer.Document = Document;
        string xpspath = Path.Combine(ReportsPath, name + ".xps");

        var doc = (FixedDocument) Viewer.Document;
        var xpsd = new XpsDocument(xpspath, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        XpsDocumentWriter xw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd);
        xw.Write(doc); //THIS IS THE LINE WHERE I GET THE ERROR
        xpsd.Close();
    }
```

Here's my stack trace.

```
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.UpdateUncompressedDataLength(Int64 dataLength)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.Crc32Calculator.CalculateStreamCrc(Stream stream)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ProgressiveCrcCalculatingStream.CalculateCrc()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.UpdateReferences(Boolean closingFlag)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.SaveContainer(Boolean closingFlag)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.SaveStream(ZipIOLocalFileBlock blockRequestingFlush, Boolean closingFlag)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOFileItemStream.Flush()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Flush()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.RemoveLocalFileBlock(ZipIOLocalFileBlock localFileBlock)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipArchive.DeleteFile(String zipFileName)
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage.IgnoredItemHelper.Delete(ValidatedPartUri partUri)
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage.CreatePartCore(Uri partUri, String contentType, CompressionOption compressionOption)
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.CreatePart(Uri partUri, String contentType, CompressionOption compressionOption)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsManager.GeneratePart(ContentType contentType, Uri partUri)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsManager.GenerateUniquePart(ContentType contentType)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument.AddFixedDocumentSequence()
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.XpsPackagingPolicy.AcquireXmlWriterForFixedDocumentSequence()
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.XpsSerializationManager.AcquireXmlWriter(Type writerType)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.ReachHierarchySimulator.SimulateBeginFixedDocumentSequence()
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.ReachHierarchySimulator.BeginConfirmToXPSStructure(Boolean mode)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.XpsSerializationManager.SaveAsXaml(Object serializedObject)
   at System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter.SaveAsXaml(Object serializedObject, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter.Write(FixedDocument fixedDocument)
```

I'm pretty confused as to what the problem would be... I don't totally understand why it's compressing anything at all, (I guess XPS uses zipped data?) much less how the data length is inconsistent.

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: The code looks basically OK, although that's a weird way to get that `doc` value. Fors starters, make sure that `doc` isn't `null`, then validate the document is some other way (load it in an active Viewer on screen).

Comment: Part 2: I notice that the error happens inside `ZipArchive.DeleteFile()`, could it be that the target file already exists? And is maybe faulty because of previous debug runs?  Start with a clean slate, use `File.Delete()` first.

Comment: So, for part one, doc is not null. It looks like it, Pages, and Pages.Children were all created correctly. I'll check out the File.Delete() thing.

Comment: This error stopped when I changed the filename of the xps file. Which is strange, because there wasn't any file there, but perhaps a hidden temporary zip file from the previous debug run?

Comment: Yes, you could use another filemanager (Total COmmander is my favorite) to make sure. Or tweak Explorer.